# How to name ftplugin filename for a composite filetype in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim, file-type

I have a composite filetype in vim called `php.wordpress`, which applies WordPress related changes to a PHP filetype.

I now want to put `php.wordpress` specific changes to file under `ftplugin` folder. For normal filetypes the filename is `filetype.vim`, but for composite filetypes, what should be the filename format? Should it be named `php.wordpress.vim`?

I went over `:help filetype` but couldn't find any documentation related to composite filetypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim will look first for `php.vim`, then for `wordpress.vim`, but not for the combined one. So, if you use the WordPress customizations only under the PHP context, it's sufficient to put it into `~/.vim/ftplugin/wordpress.vim`.

If you have different contexts (e.g. `html.wordpress`), you'd need to put an additional conditional in there (e.g. `if &filetype =~# '^php\.`)

Comment: Thanks. Right now it is only for php files. So I will just create a `wordpress.vim` file. (BTW I have to wait for another 6 minutes before I can accept this answer)

Comment: I just tried it, but whatever I am putting in `~/.vim/ftplugin/wordpress.vim` is not getting picked up.

Comment: Is the file sourced (check `:scriptnames`). Note that the second ftplugin must not use the `if exists('b:did_ftplugin')` guard (or adapt it).

Comment: The file is indeed getting included. I have defined some configuration for syntastic plugin but they don't seem to be used. I guess it is a problem with syntastic plugin.

Comment: Probably; not every plugin handles composite filetypes.